# HttpClient GET returns 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit.net

I am trying to run integration tests on a simple controller that returns data from entity framework. I have written unit tests and all work as expected.

I have wired up xUnit Integration tests but when I run a simple Get to my controller I am getting a 404 not found. If I start the project in the browser and run a get via postman, I hit the controller and action correctly.

My xUnit TestFixture Class

```cs
public sealed class TestFixture<TStartup> : IDisposable where TStartup : class
{
    public readonly TestServer Server;
    public readonly HttpClient Client;

    public TestFixture()
    {
        var builder = BuildWebHost();
        Server = new TestServer(builder);
        Client = Server.CreateClient();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost()
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
              {
                  config.Sources.Clear();
                  config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                  config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
              });
        return host;
    }
}
```

My controller test class

```cs
public class FlowApiControllerTests : IClassFixture<TestFixture<Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public FlowApiControllerTests(TestFixture<Startup> fixture)
    {
        _httpClient = fixture.Client;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_FlowApiTest()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/flowapi");

        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FlowApi>>(content);
        model.Count.Should().Be(2);
    }
}
```

and finally my controller

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FlowApiController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IFlowApiRepository _repository;

    public FlowApiController(IFlowApiRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    // GET: api/FlowApi
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var result = await _repository.Select<FlowApi>();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why I am not hitting the controller within my tests but can hit it from postman.

Comment: Replace TextFixture class declaration as such  `public sealed class TestFixture<TStartup> : IDisposable where TStartup : class` with `public sealed class TestFixture<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Ajeet Kumar for pointing me in the direction of WebApplicationFactory, I have taken the approach from [the ASP.NET Core Integration Test docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#customize-webapplicationfactory) and I have modified my TestFixture class to reflect that approach. I also imported the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing. My TestFixture class now looks like

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ApiContext>));

            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                services.Remove(descriptor);
            }

            // Add ApplicationDbContext using an in-memory database for testing.
            services.AddDbContext<ApiContext>((options, context) =>
            {
                context.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
            });

            services.AddTransient<DatabaseSeeder>();

            // Build the service provider.
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApiContext>();

                // Ensure the database is created.
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                try
                {
                    // Seed the database with test data.
                    var seeder = scopedServices.GetService<DatabaseSeeder>();
                    seeder.SeedFlowApplicationData().Wait();
```

Comment: I also imported the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing. This was it for me.